# How to keep time from (1: interval*3600sec) when plotting distinct interval averages

Tags: matlab, time, plot, average, intervals

I need to plot 10-min. averages of a waveform. So I have written the code below in MATLAB:

```
time= 1:54000         % sec.
ARC_A1= ones(54000,1) % each row is associated with each of above seconds in order

intervals= 54000/(10*60)  % No. of 10min. intervals in 14hr.*3600=50400sec. 
k=1;
for n=1:intervals
    for (i=1+600*(n-1):600*n)
        sum_ARC_A1(i)= sum(ARC_A1(1+600*(n-1):600*n)) ;
    end
    ave_ARC_A1(i)= sum_ARC_A1(i) / 600;
    ARC_A1_ave(k)= ave_ARC_A1(i)
    t_ARC(k,length(1+600*(n-1):600*n))= 1+600*(n-1):600*n;      ##1
    k= k+1
end

t_ARC 
plot(t_ARC, ARC_A1_ave)                                     ##2
```

How can I have **##1** corrected so that I can plot "ARC_A1_ave" over the complete time of all intervals i.e. 54000sec to have something alike plot below:

(Need to Keep like this fig. x-axis Time from 0 to 54000sec. when plotting ARC_A1_ave)

[To achieve alike this Fig. for ARC_A1_ave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haPDK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have waveform stored in `Mx2` matrix `Data` in form of `[time voltage]` with **known** and **constant** sample rate `spm` (samples per minute).

```
[M,N]=size(Data);      % read the size of the Data
ii=1;                  % counter
StepSize=10*spm        % index increment

while ii<Data-StepSize % loop untill end of Data
%% Calculate mean value within ii and ii+StepSize (10 minutes) and assign it to 3rd column.
  Data(ii:ii+StepSize,3)=mean(Data(ii:ii+StepSize,2));
  ii=ii+StepSize;      % Step for another 10minutes interval
end

plot(Data(:,1),Data(:,2),'b:');
hold on
plot(Data(:,1),Data(:,3),'b');
hold off
```

Comment: 1st column is your `time`, second one is `ARC_A1` and third one si `ARC_A1_ave`. `spm = 60`.